# Back office and front end separation

Tags: c#, .net, security, roles, asp.net-identity-2

We are implementing identity 2.0 with an admin CMS and a login area for front end users.

Should they be separated by Role alone?  So admins have their own roles and front end users have their own roles?  Then just redirect after login and authenticate by role depending on if you are in /userarea/ (front end users) and /cms/ (back office)?

On that note since it's cookie based do you have to redirect before you can check the signed in user against their roles?

Comment: Not true, you don't have to redirect before you check roles but rather after.

Answer (score 2):

Separation by Role would be the most common way of doing this.  That said, these Roles can be assigned with much more granularity then top-level objects (folders) on your site.   For example, there could be a /userarea/admins/ with the Admin Role.

There are also security levels being assigned to the individual Roles.  Where the entire path of the object is checked, and the highest (or most restrictive) 'level' of security assigned to any part the path, would be selected, and the user would have to be a member of that Role to be allowed access.

The redirection is redirecting the user to the authentication service, which is often a different system from the ones providing the sites pages.  After the user has been authenticated, he or she is provided with an cookie containing a unique identifier that would tell your security proxy server which objects said user had access to.

Comment: OK - I want to check a user's roles before I actually sign them in.  The user manager PasswordSignIn() signs them in, but how can I pass in a username and password just to retrieve a user ID and not log them in?

Comment: Ah - do I have to use FindByName?  So I don't necessarily need to know the password to check against a role.

Comment: It would depend on the user registry.  Most I've used/seen would not require that you specifically know the users password.  Many web-security portals will perform an LDAP bind call against the user registry, with the uid and encrypted password (you have it, but do not 'know' it).  The returned information (if successful) would contain what Roles and/or Groups the user has permission to access, as well as expiration info for that credential - lifetime, timeouts, etc.  A web-security portal will do nearly all this work for you.